# VirtualBox guest fullscreen picking up wrong monitor size

Tags: linux, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I am running Xubuntu 11.04 as a Host, with a Xubuntu 11.04 VirtualBox Guest OS.  I have it set up so that when I put the Guest OS in full screen, it can detect the monitor settings and resizes.  However, it seems to only be able to pick up the primary screen's resolution.  I'm running on a laptop with an external monitor plugged in, and I want to run the Guest OS on the external monitor, which is the second screen, and is a different size than the laptop screen.  I can't seem to choose the actual resolution of the second monitor in the Guest OS Display settings.

Any ideas how I can get it to detect the correct resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Change the displayed VM to your External monitor.

Use the toolbar, which can be accessed by pressing `[HOST Key] + Home` and select view/virtual screen and change the host screen.

`HOST` key usually is the `Right-Ctrl` key.